# Laravel remember_token

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как сгенерировать токен? Он у меня  в базе пустой,и поэтому я не могу авторизироваться!

Answer (score 1):

Токен генерируется если пользователь авторизуется с "флагом запомнить"
авторизация такого пользователя происходит так:

```
Auth::attempt($credentials, true);
```